# Combining Maybe and IO monads for DOM read/write

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, ramda.js, fantasyland

I'm trying to cook up a simple example **using IO and Maybe monads**. The program reads a node from the DOM and writes some `innerHTML` to it.

What I'm hung up on is the combination of IO and Maybe, e.g. `IO (Maybe NodeList)`.

**How do I short circuit or throw an error with this setup?**

I could use `getOrElse` to extract a value or set a default value, but setting the default value to just an empty array doesn't help anything.

```
import R from 'ramda';
import { IO, Maybe } from 'ramda-fantasy';
const Just    = Maybe.Just;
const Nothing = Maybe.Nothing;

// $ :: String -> Maybe NodeList
const $ = (selector) => {
  const res = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return res.length ? Just(res) : Nothing();
}

// getOrElse :: Monad m => m a -> a -> m a
var getOrElse = R.curry(function(val, m) {
    return m.getOrElse(val);
});


// read :: String -> IO (Maybe NodeList)
const read = selector => 
  IO(() => $(selector));

// write :: String -> DOMNode -> IO
const write = text => 
                  (domNode) => 
                    IO(() => domNode.innerHTML = text);

const prog = read('#app')
                  // What goes here? How do I short circuit or error?
                  .map(R.head)
                  .chain(write('Hello world'));

prog.runIO();
```

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh2ghQd99-ljiPys8Bd

Comment: Here's a version with Either instead of Maybe: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh36r7GT7TR1ksMcWMM

Maybe that's the way to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try writing an `EitherIO` monad transformer. Monad transformers allow you to combine the effects of two monads into a single monad. They can be written in a generic way such that we can create dynamic combinations of monads as needed, but here I'm just going to demonstrate a static coupling of `Either` and `IO`.

First we need a way to go from `IO (Either e a)` to `EitherIO e a` and a way to go from `EitherIO e a` to `IO (Either e a)`

```
EitherIO :: IO (Either e a) -> EitherIO e a
runEitherIO :: EitherIO e a -> IO (Either e a)
```

And we'll need a couple helper functions for taking other flat types to our nested monad

```
EitherIO.liftEither :: Either e a -> EitherIO e a
EitherIO.liftIO :: IO a -> EitherIO e a
```

To conform with fantasy land, our new `EitherIO` monad has a `chain` method and `of` function and obeys the monad laws. For your convenience, I also implemented the functor interface with the `map` method.

**EitherIO.js**

```
import { IO, Either } from 'ramda-fantasy'
const { Left, Right, either } = Either

// type EitherIO e a = IO (Either e a)
export const EitherIO = runEitherIO => ({
  // runEitherIO :: IO (Either e a)
  runEitherIO, 
  // map :: EitherIO e a => (a -> b) -> EitherIO e b
  map: f =>
    EitherIO(runEitherIO.map(m => m.map(f))),
  // chain :: EitherIO e a => (a -> EitherIO e b) -> EitherIO e b
  chain: f =>
    EitherIO(runEitherIO.chain(
      either (x => IO.of(Left(x)), (x => f(x).runEitherIO))))
})

// of :: a -> EitherIO e a
EitherIO.of = x => EitherIO(IO.of(Right.of(x)))

// liftEither :: Either e a -> EitherIO e a
export const liftEither = m => EitherIO(IO.of(m))

// liftIO :: IO a -> EitherIO e a
export const liftIO = m => EitherIO(m.map(Right))

// runEitherIO :: EitherIO e a -> IO (Either e a)
export const runEitherIO = m => m.runEitherIO
```

---

**Adapting your program to use EitherIO**

What's nice about this is your `read` and `write` functions are fine as they are - nothing in your program needs to change except for how we structure the calls in `prog`

```
import { compose } from 'ramda'
import { IO, Either } from 'ramda-fantasy'
const { Left, Right, either } = Either
import { EitherIO, liftEither, liftIO } from './EitherIO'

// ...

// prog :: IO (Either Error String)
const prog =
  EitherIO(read('#app'))
    .chain(compose(liftIO, write('Hello world')))
    .runEitherIO

either (throwError, console.log) (prog.runIO())
```

---

**Additional explanation**

```
// prog :: IO (Either Error String)
const prog =
  // read already returns IO (Either String DomNode)
  // so we can plug it directly into EitherIO to work with our new type
  EitherIO(read('#app'))
    // write only returns IO (), so we have to use liftIO to return the correct EitherIO type that .chain is expecting
    .chain(compose(liftIO, write('Hello world')))
    // we don't care that EitherIO was used to do the hard work
    // unwrap the EitherIO and just return (IO Either)
    .runEitherIO

// this actually runs the program and clearly shows the fork
// if prog.runIO() causes an error, it will throw
// otherwise it will output any IO to the console
either (throwError, console.log) (prog.runIO())
```

---

**Checking for errors**

Go ahead and change `'#app'` to some non-matching selector (eg) `'#foo'`. Re-run the program and you'll see the appropriate error barfed into the console

```
Error: Could not find DOMNode
```

---

**Runnable demo**

You made it this far. Here's a runnable demo as your reward: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh5NqerKrROGRiRkkoA

---

---

**Generic transform using EitherT**

A monad transformer takes a monad as an argument and creates a new monad. In this case, `EitherT` will take some monad `M` and create a monad that effectively behaves has `M (Either e a)`.

So now we have some way to create new monads

```
// EitherIO :: IO (Either e a) -> EitherIO e a
const EitherIO = EitherT (IO)
```

And again we have functions to lifting the flat types into our nested type

```
EitherIO.liftEither :: Either e a -> EitherIO e a
EitherIO.liftIO :: IO a -> EitherIO e a
```

Lastly a custom run function that makes it easier to handle our nested `IO (Either e a)` type - notice, one layer of abstraction (`IO`) is removed so we only have to think about the `Either`

```
runEitherIO :: EitherIO e a -> Either e a
```

---

**EitherT**

is the bread and butter - the primary difference you see here is that `EitherT` accepts a monad `M` as an input and creates/returns a new Monad type

```
// EitherT.js
import { Either } from 'ramda-fantasy'
const { Left, Right, either } = Either

export const EitherT = M => {
   const Monad = runEitherT => ({
     runEitherT,
     chain: f =>
       Monad(runEitherT.chain(either (x => M.of(Left(x)),
                                      x => f(x).runEitherT)))
   })
   Monad.of = x => Monad(M.of(Right(x)))
   return Monad
}

export const runEitherT = m => m.runEitherT
```

**EitherIO**

can now be implemented in terms of `EitherT` – a dramatically simplified implementation

```
import { IO, Either } from 'ramda-fantasy'
import { EitherT, runEitherT } from './EitherT'

export const EitherIO = EitherT (IO)

// liftEither :: Either e a -> EitherIO e a
export const liftEither = m => EitherIO(IO.of(m))

// liftIO :: IO a -> EitherIO e a
export const liftIO = m => EitherIO(m.map(Either.Right))

// runEitherIO :: EitherIO e a -> Either e a
export const runEitherIO = m => runEitherT(m).runIO()
```

**Updates to our program**

```
import { EitherIO, liftEither, liftIO, runEitherIO } from './EitherIO'

// ...

// prog :: () -> Either Error String
const prog = () =>
  runEitherIO(EitherIO(read('#app'))
    .chain(R.compose(liftIO, write('Hello world'))))

either (throwError, console.log) (prog())
```

---

**Runnable demo using EitherT**

Here's the runnable code using EitherT: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh8S2NZ8ufBStUSK1EU

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I'll read and reread until I understand.

Comment: You're very welcome. Monad transformers are a new study for me and it's taken a good week of reading to start to get a good grasp on them. I think I was originally making them more complicated than necessary! I wanted to cover writing a generic transformer `EitherT` that would let you do something like `const EitherIO = EitherT (IO)`. This let's you create dynamic nesting of monads instead of the static coupling I wrote in my answer. I'll try to get around to that this weekend if I have time ^_^

Comment: I found this in my own research https://github.com/mattbierner/akh-either Not sure if it'll be helpful

Comment: the akh repositories are very useful and thorough but pretty highly engineered. You'll have to chase around several files to see how things fit together, but it's all very well written.

Comment: I adapted some of the code found in akh's EitherT transformer and implemented a simplified version for you here in an update to this answer. Monad transformers are quite fun!

Comment: @naomik  why do you wrap the result of  the chain function back in the Monad in the EitherT implementation?  I would expect that for map but not for chain...  THanks

Comment: @akaphenom the type of `chain` is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` so if `m` is `EitherT`, `chain` must return an `EitherT`. The *trick* here is we're also expecting the user-supplied function to return an `EitherT`, so in that case we would end up with `EitherT`, wrapped around another `EitherT`, which is why we call `.runEitherT` to unwrap the additional level of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a helper function that will conditionally chain with another IO producing function if the given predicate returns true. If it returns false it will produce an `IO ()`.

```
// (a → Boolean) → (a → IO ()) → a → IO ()
const ioWhen = curry((pred, ioFn, val) =>
  pred(val) ? ioFn(val) : IO(() => void 0))

const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)

const read = selector => 
  IO(() => $(selector))

const write = text => domNode =>
  IO(() => domNode.innerHTML = text)

const prog = read('#app').chain(
  ioWhen(node => node != null, write('Hello world'))
)

prog.runIO();
```